# add some validation in odoo 17 point_of_sale set_discount function in file models.js

Tags: javascript, odoo, point-of-sale, odoo-17

> in odoo 17 pos, there is a function named set_discount
> in models.js file , i want to add extra validation in it like this :

```
set_discount(discount) {
    var parsed_discount =
        typeof discount === "number"
            ? discount
            : isNaN(parseFloat(discount))
            ? 0
            : oParseFloat("" + discount);
    var disc = Math.min(Math.max(parsed_discount || 0, 0), 100);this.product.id });
    
    //here i want to get max discount from product.product
    
    //var maxDiscount = this.product.maxDiscount;
    //if(disc > maxDiscount){
        //alert("discount > max discount");
        //return;
    //}

    this.discount = disc;
    this.discountStr = "" + disc;
}
```

> how can i do this (var maxDiscount = this.product.maxDiscount;)
> in odoo 17 js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  patch the `orderline` component

***Example:***

```js
/* @odoo-modules */

import { Orderline } from "@point_of_sale/app/store/models";
import { patch } from "@web/core/utils/patch";

patch(Orderline.prototype, {
    set_discount(discount) {
        var self = this;
        super.set_discount(discount);
        var maxDiscount = self.product.max_discount;
        if(self.discount > maxDiscount){
            self.discount = 0.0;
            self.discountStr = "";
        }
    }
})
```

You need to click the `Backspace` button to undo the last operation.

Add the js file under assets as follows:

```
'assets': {
    'point_of_sale._assets_pos': [
        'MODULE_NAME/static/src/**/*',
    ],
},
```

You can use the pos popup to show notifications to users

***Example:***

```js
self.env.services.popup.add(ErrorPopup, {
    title: _t("Invalid discount"),
    body: _t("You are not allowed to set a discount ..."),
});
```

***Edit:***

Override the `_loader_params_product_product` function to force Odoo to set the value of the product max discount

***Example:***

```py
class PosSession(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.session'

    def _loader_params_product_product(self):
        res = super()._loader_params_product_product()
        res['search_params']['fields'].append('max_discount')
        return res
```

Use the same field name (`this.product.max_discount`) in js code

Comment: var maxDiscount = self.product.maxDiscount;
in this line : the maxDiscount is undefined
how can i load this field

thank you so much ?

Comment: Did you define `maxDiscount`?

Comment: no, sorry
i'm beginner in this scope

i defined it in product_product.py (python part)  but in javascript i don't know how to get it

Comment: what should i do bro ? @Kenly

Comment: Check my edit, I added an example

Comment: you are a legend thank you so much 